# Dataframe .assign() function repeats output in new column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Am trying to add a new column to my df with .assign() as the soundex value of one of the other columns.  Using jellyfish lib which works fine.  But I'm getting a repeat value in the new column.  its like its taking the first value, and using that first value for all rows of the new column.

I've tried two versions of doing this, with a lambda and without lambda. lambda version is commented out below, but outputs same result.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('C:\\path\\my.csv', header=0)#.set_index('name1')
df2 = df1.assign(soundexMd5=jellyfish.soundex(str(df1['name1'])))
#df2 = df1.assign(soundexMd5=lambda x: jellyfish.soundex(str(df1['name1'])))
#df2 = df1.assign(soundexMd5=lambda x: jellyfish.soundex(str(x.name1)))
print(df2)
```

Notice I also have set_index() commented out, bcz that causes errors when I do that.  When i use set_index('name1'), it throws:
KeyError: 'name1'
on 'name1' on the .assign line of code.

> When I try to set_index('name1'), and run the 3rd .assign above, reference x.name1, it errors with:
>   AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name1'

Source csv looks like this:

```
"name1"
"Yolanda"
"Push Notify"
"Yolanda"
"test1"
"test2"
```

See below 0453 is the output for Yolanda, but it repeats for all rows.

```
name1 soundexMd5
0                     Yolanda       0453
1                 Push Notify       0453
2                     Yolanda       0453
3                       test1       0453
4                       test2       0453
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) for run function for each value:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('C:\\path\\my.csv', header=0)
df2 = df1.assign(soundexMd5=df1['name1'].apply(jellyfish.soundex))
```

If need convert to strings add [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df2 = df1.assign(soundexMd5=df1['name1'].astype(str).apply(jellyfish.soundex))
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, is using apply ok? i've read using apply is not recommended.  I guess thats when its on the whole dataframe.  Is it ok for the one column.

Comment: @Ron - It depends what need. If there is some better alternative like function `jellyfish.soundex` then use it.